# Redirecting traffic from old ".WordPress.com" blog to privately hosted WordPress blog?

Tags: wordpress.com-hosting, seo, migration

I've got a blog hosted on .wordpress.com, ie the free version.

I'm thinking of re-activating my hosting package so I can have my own WP installation, and therefore have more customisation options open to me etc.

I'm getting traffic from search engines, how can I redirect this traffic to my new location?

Once I have the new one setup, I would prefer people to view that instead of my old site, what can I do to achieve this, whilst retaining my position in search engines?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Didn't try this myself (self-hosted from the start), but this seems fitting guide for your situation:
[How to Migrate your Blog from WordPress.com to a Personal Domain ( Digital Inspiration )](http://www.labnol.org/internet/migrate-wordpress-blog-to-own-domain/12776/)

Comment: James.Elsey, if that answers your question, please mark it as an 'accepted' answer.

Comment: I was planning to, but at the time I had to "wait 3 minutes" so came back later :)

Comment: Ahh, sorry about that :)

Answer (score 4):

It looks like this is now a standard feature on Wordpress.com.

http://en.support.wordpress.com/offsite-redirect/

Comment: Standard, albeit one that costs money (an "Upgrade").