# Migrating from WordPress.com to self-hosted site and autoforward visitors?

Tags: wordpress.com-hosting, migration

Having moved to my hosting my own WordPress blogsite I now need to ensure that readers find the new site rather than the old WordPress.com site.  What is the best mechanism for doing this?

Comment: Do the sites have the same domain name ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Redirecting traffic from old ".WordPress.com" blog to privately hosted WordPress blog?](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/2044/redirecting-traffic-from-old-wordpress-com-blog-to-privately-hosted-wordpress)

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to do this without losing your traffic is to use the WordPress.com [Site Redirect](http://en.support.wordpress.com/site-redirect/).  It keeps the **yourblog.wordpress.com** address active and points traffic to your new **yourblog.com** domain.  You would be essentially paying the registration fee for your old domain at $12.00/year.

Periodically through this process you should be informing your readers to visit you at **yourblog.com** so that you can stop paying for the redirect after a year.  Begin promoting the new address in your email signature, forum posts, etc. until people are used to the new address, then let the site redirect lapse.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use a redirect 301 moved permanently.

This is typically done in your .htaccess.

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^.:]+\.)*oldwebsite\.com\.?(:[0-9]*)?$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ http://www.preferredwebsite.net/$1 [R=301,L]
```

There are several methods, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URL_redirection .

Comment: Hello Wyck

in principle yes.

going from 

http://braincram.wordpress.com 

to 

www.braincram.co.uk


Thanks Ray, I'll check that out.

Yours 
MJR