# Moving WordPress.com theme and widget settings to self-hosted site?

Tags: themes, widgets, wordpress.com-hosting, migration, options

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Migrating from WordPress.com to self-hosted site and autoforward visitors?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/12553/migrating-from-wordpress-com-to-self-hosted-site-and-autoforward-visitors)

How can I move theme and plugin (widget) settings from a WordPress.com site to a self-hosted installation? My client is moving from `hissite.wordpress.com` to his own host at `hissite.com`.

I have moved over the content using the Import/Export feature, but I can't access the theme and widget plugin files, since WordPress.com offers no FTP access. We also don't want to [pay WordPress.com to move these files over](http://en.support.wordpress.com/guided-transfer/).

Comment: This question has been asked and answered many time. Flagged as duplicate

Comment: @anu - I searched and could not find the correct post, please point me to the right article that will help me and I'll delete my question

Comment: @Roland: It was asked under different names, you can follow the "possible duplicate" comments to find the others. If others vote to close this as a duplicate too it will automatically redirect there.

Comment: @Roland: I re-wrote your question to make the focus really clear. If you prefer your version you can always click "edit" and roll back to it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First off, check if the theme is available in wordpress.org themes: http://wordpress.org/extend/themes/

If it's not, find the name of the theme developer and contact them. Many developers of wordpress.com themes are happy for people to use their themes on self-hosted WordPress blogs. The developer's name and contact details can be found by looking at style.css. You can see the content of style.css by viewing the CSS file in your browser. Alternatively, navigate to style.css for the theme you want in the wordpress.com theme repository: https://wpcom-themes.svn.automattic.com/ This is also where you download the theme.

You must seek permission from the theme's author before you download and use their theme unless the theme's style.css includes a note to say it is released under the GPL. If it's GPL then permission has already been given.

For plugins, you need to download them from wordpress.org. If they are not available there you will need to find acceptable replacements or track down who developed them and ask if the plugins are going to be made available.

Comment: Thanx for the advise,, I've followed it and managed to solve my problem

Answer (score 0):

EDIT:

Here is what WordPress.com has to say on moving your blog to self hosted: http://en.support.wordpress.com/moving-a-blog/#moving-to-wordpress-org

IGNORE:

Here is my method of moving a wordpress install from subdomain.example.com to example.com Using the tools I have its the quickest way for me to move a dev install to a live install.

1. Compress all files of WP into zip and upload to new site.
2. Extract files on new domain. Create new database on new domain.
3. Update wp-config to point to new domain.
4. Export database from subdomain as an SQL file.
5. Open SQL file in a text editor program and do a find and replace.
6. Find `http://subdomain.example.com` replace with `http://www.example.com`
7. Import SQL into new database.
8. Navigate to new domain.
9. All done

Comment: @brady - But the site is hosted on wordpress.com which I do not have ftp details for.

Comment: this is an migration from wordpress.com. and it's a duplicate question

Comment: @anu - where is the duplicate, I still can't find it ;-)

Comment: Sorry didn't realise it was for a WordPress.com site.

Comment: @brady - I managed to move over all the content, problem is I want to move the theme files, plugin files etc as well, could you direct me on how to do this

Comment: @Roland: Aha, that is an aspect we overlooked, we only thought about the "redirect existing visitors" part. Can you edit your question to make this very clear? "I don't need to know how to redirect existing visitors, but what is the best way to preserve the theme and plugins?" is a suggestion to start with :-)

Comment: Are you not able to find the same theme for download elsewhere? Find the theme and add to your install of wordpress. I dont think wordpress.com allows access to its themes files. It does say if its a premium theme that it cannot be moved. Plugins you may have to just install one by one.

Comment: @Jan - Edited my question, hope this time around it will make more sense ;-)